# iOS10 UserDefaults file location/path?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults, xcode8

I'm trying to view the stored keys and values that I save to User Defaults with this code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(myStringVar, forKey: "my_key")
```

But I can't find the location of the file containing this data in iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You find your user default value in list file using below code

```
    var path: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [AnyObject]
    let folder: String = path[0] as! String
    NSLog("Your NSUserDefaults are stored in this folder: %@/Preferences", folder)
```

At this path you will find a plist file which is named by your <bundle identifier>.plist

Comment: Thank you! This code worked and the correct path was: `/Users/jejo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/**ID**/data/Containers/Data/Application/**ID**/Library/Preferences`

Answer (score 2):

You can also check it by typing print command in AppDelegate.swift file under

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {  
    print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)
}
```

When app builds it will print exact path in Debug area. You should then be able to locate .plist file which contains key-value pairs for data you stored.